# Return index value based on MAX of another column, by month, within pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, data-manipulation

I have a data set of tickets, by month, as well as Duration (in minutes) of some actions that take place throughout the course of our tickets.

Ive created a pivot table and added custom measures to find the 50th & 90th percentile, as well as the max for each month.

What I'd ideally like to do is, in the pivot table, have the Max value of each duration displayed (like ive been able to) but have that value that is displayed be a hyperlink based on the corresponding ticket ID. I cannot slice/filter (or I havent been able to) without break the other duration columns and/or month fields in the table.

I asked this yesterday but neglected to create a minimal, reproducible example and instead linked to a spreadsheet.  Thinking about it late last night I figured some here may be averse to downloading a rogue .xlsx document.  I'm including a sample of the data in a code block below, as well as a screenshot of my pivot table, examples of my existing formulas, but am leaving the link to the .xlsx doc which resides in my google drive, for those who may be open to looking at it.

I've manually written formulas to show what I'm looking to achieve, but Im hoping to find a way to make this dynamically populated within the pivot table.

I am open to other options than a pivot table as I dont need the drill-down granularity of the pivot table, what I do need is to be able to update the RAWData sheet with data for each additional month as we go, and be able to 'Refresh Pivot table' and have the new month included. I've been able to get things working outside of a pivot table, somewhat, using an `INDEX` function but I cant seem to get it without having to manually define where one month ends and the next starts somehow. But Ideally, id like all the results/calculations (on the `calc` page) in a dynamic table that will update when I add additional months of data.

Additionally, I'd like to use the REPLACE function (with `IF(ISERROR)`) to remove the co/ with  rather than use the `&Right(xx,LEN(xx)-3)` function. In the future Im looking to get the data source of the RAW data to update and omit the `co/` (which I would prefer in the long term, for multiple use cases) and if I use LEN, i'll have to go through and update all of my formulas or lose the `TIC` from the `ID` field which will effectively break the hyperlinking.

The workbook/.xlsx file contains two sheets. One titled 'calcs' which contains the pivot table and my mock-up of the desired result, the other titled 'RAWData' containing the dataset I'm using.  I formatted the data as a Table titled 'RAW'.

[image: Screenshot of 'calc' spreadsheet containing pivot table & example of ideal format]

"**Count of ID**" is just using the pivot table's native `Count of ID` feature.
"**p50 of**" & "**p90 of**" custom measures within the pivot table use the formula: `=PERCENTILE.INC([DurationX],0.5)` or .09 respectively, where `[DurationX]` changes based on the column we're looking at. I set up each of these individually.
"**Max of Duration**" is just using the pivot table's native `MAX of [DurationX]` feature, where `[DurationX]` changes based on the column we're looking at.

The "**Ideal Max of DurationX**" below the main pivot table is the example of how I would like the results in the "**Max of DurationX**" column above it to be returned.  It displays the max value just like the pivot table above does, but creates a hyperlink, based on the corresponding ID of that max value. I've manually created this formula to achieve this, but I had to go through and :

`=HYPERLINK("https://someurl.com/"&RIGHT(RAWData!A9,LEN(RAWData!A9)-3),RAWData!B9)`

I have found an example of using `INDEX` and `MATCH(MAXIFS` do this but it requires me to set up a completely separate table apart from the pivot table which, will work if its the only solution, but is not ideal. This formula currently is:

`=INDEX(RAW[ID],MATCH(MAXIFS(RAW[PreDetection],RAW[Date/Time(in UTC)],">="&A3,RAW[Date/Time(in UTC)],"<"&A14),RAW[PreDetection],0))`  where A3:A14 are the months 1/1/2023:12/1/2023 (formatted `mmm`)

Here is the content of RAWData sheet (in CSV format)

```
ID,Duration1,Duration2,Duration3,Duration4,Duration5,Duration6,Duration7,Date/Time(in UTC)
co/TICKET-0001,2.22,0.63,0.63,37,122,147.49,267.27,1/4/23 7:41
co/TICKET-0002,3.23,2.27,2.27,28,121.17,23.61,141.55,1/5/23 20:17
co/TICKET-0003,5.21,0.78,0.78,10,14.13,39.86,48.78,1/7/23 1:50
co/TICKET-0004,2.23,1.95,1.95,12,58.17,40.71,96.64,1/9/23 5:16
co/TICKET-0005,5.23,0.53,0.53,18,25.47,9.84,30.08,1/10/23 18:30
co/TICKET-0006,5.21,0.97,0.97,4,8,56.24,59.04,1/13/23 9:40
co/TICKET-0007,2.23,2.18,2.18,10,13,197.36,208.14,1/13/23 18:58
co/TICKET-0008,7.22,0.43,0.43,8,21,138.62,152.4,1/18/23 16:40
co/TICKET-0009,4.6,0.37,0.37,3,5,101.77,102.17,1/18/23 22:05
co/TICKET-0010,3.2,1.2,1.2,14,29,18.67,44.47,1/19/23 11:31
co/TICKET-0011,5.24,0.6,0.6,11,65,37.91,97.66,1/23/23 10:19
co/TICKET-0012,4.23,0.73,0.73,8,11.15,243.75,250.67,1/24/23 2:10
co/TICKET-0013,3.25,1.3,1.3,4,6,72.55,75.3,1/24/23 10:07
co/TICKET-0014,6.24,2.43,2.43,11,12.22,37.65,43.62,1/24/23 23:55
co/TICKET-0015,3.23,0.83,0.83,6,8,40.12,44.9,1/25/23 0:38
co/TICKET-0016,6.22,0.35,0.35,6,49,25.25,68.03,1/26/23 16:33
co/TICKET-0017,6.24,1.85,1.85,2,12.82,94.3,100.87,1/30/23 6:53
co/TICKET-0018,3.23,0.62,0.62,5,9,111.63,117.41,1/30/23 16:33
co/TICKET-0019,4.22,0.68,0.68,8,42,62.41,100.19,2/1/23 20:35
co/TICKET-0020,5.21,1.77,1.77,2,1,28.13,28.92,2/2/23 19:03
co/TICKET-0021,5.22,0.68,0.68,6,10,35.47,40.26,2/3/23 13:04
co/TICKET-0022,3.22,0.48,0.48,10,15.22,66.48,78.48,2/3/23 15:02
co/TICKET-0023,11.21,0.67,0.67,8,53.35,193.27,235.41,2/4/23 6:28
co/TICKET-0024,11.21,0.78,0.78,6,15.18,130.07,134.04,2/4/23 15:07
co/TICKET-0025,3.26,0.42,0.42,6,12,31.07,39.8,2/6/23 2:36
co/TICKET-0026,5.24,0.7,0.7,7,17.57,52.11,64.44,2/6/23 15:05
co/TICKET-0027,3.2,1.1,1.1,3,5,212.66,214.46,2/6/23 20:22
co/TICKET-0028,5.21,0.58,0.58,3,8,170.49,173.28,2/7/23 8:30
co/TICKET-0029,4.22,0.62,0.62,6,14,43.71,53.49,2/8/23 21:46
co/TICKET-0030,2.21,4.62,4.62,61,71,1261.76,1330.55,2/9/23 12:11
co/TICKET-0031,5.25,0.32,0.32,7,49,52.24,96,2/9/23 17:05
co/TICKET-0032,2.21,0.78,0.78,11,14.23,48.62,60.64,2/10/23 17:16
co/TICKET-0033,3.2,0.45,0.45,4,7,35.72,39.52,2/12/23 0:42
co/TICKET-0034,3.22,0.8,0.8,4,9,35.88,41.66,2/12/23 2:20
co/TICKET-0035,3.18,0.65,0.65,6,9.8,54.13,60.76,2/12/23 10:32
co/TICKET-0036,3.22,2.03,2.03,4,6,32.7,35.48,2/13/23 1:18
co/TICKET-0037,2.22,0.5,0.5,9,22,58.28,78.05,2/13/23 9:56
co/TICKET-0038,3.22,0.75,0.75,4,6,25.61,28.39,2/13/23 14:20
co/TICKET-0039,3.22,0.23,0.23,12,21.48,28.57,46.84,2/13/23 19:00
co/TICKET-0040,5.23,0.6,0.6,5,62.25,32.57,89.59,2/13/23 21:54
co/TICKET-0041,2.25,0.62,0.62,6,9,37.78,44.53,2/14/23 6:13
co/TICKET-0042,5.23,0.28,0.28,7,70.87,54.22,119.86,2/16/23 23:01
co/TICKET-0043,2.23,4.72,4.72,11,31,59.25,88.02,2/21/23 1:19
co/TICKET-0044,6.28,0.67,0.67,2,7,83.02,83.74,2/22/23 5:18
co/TICKET-0045,5.23,1.2,1.2,7,14,218.17,226.94,2/22/23 19:55
co/TICKET-0046,5.24,0.75,0.75,14,79.88,35.44,110.08,2/23/23 0:36
co/TICKET-0047,2.25,2.43,2.43,5,6,74.14,77.89,2/23/23 18:43
co/TICKET-0048,5.25,0.8,0.8,6,11,291.39,297.15,2/25/23 8:39
co/TICKET-0049,6.24,0.72,0.72,6,12.47,22.96,29.18,2/25/23 22:13
co/TICKET-0050,3.23,0.88,0.88,3,5,68.32,70.08,2/27/23 5:44
co/TICKET-0051,2.25,2.02,2.02,8,10.4,103.58,111.73,2/27/23 13:43
co/TICKET-0052,2.26,0.65,0.65,6,7.2,24.74,29.68,2/27/23 17:40
co/TICKET-0053,5.24,0.7,0.7,3,27,61.96,88.73,2/27/23 17:53
co/TICKET-0054,5.23,0.6,-1,4,8,59.32,62.09,3/1/23 3:28
co/TICKET-0055,7.22,1,117,6,132,32.69,157.47,3/3/23 2:33
co/TICKET-0056,5.33,0.27,1,6,13,94.13,101.8,3/3/23 22:24
co/TICKET-0057,4.28,0.72,-1,9,13.2,209.34,218.26,3/4/23 11:01
co/TICKET-0058,9.27,0.13,-4,7,12.4,63.18,66.31,3/6/23 16:57
co/TICKET-0059,7.26,0.75,-2,6,12,11.35,16.09,3/6/23 23:16
co/TICKET-0060,3.24,0.57,10,5,19,136.46,152.22,3/8/23 17:40
co/TICKET-0061,5.27,0.9,0,5,12.48,21.7,28.91,3/9/23 1:29
co/TICKET-0062,5.24,0.82,53,13,73.17,34.96,102.89,3/9/23 17:40
co/TICKET-0063,2.24,1.75,8,57,69,208.75,1160.54,3/10/23 3:23
co/TICKET-0064,5.23,0.4,48,5,59.23,8.5,62.51,3/10/23 12:47
co/TICKET-0065,15.17,0.43,24,25,65.22,59.6,109.65,3/14/23 14:00
co/TICKET-0066,5.25,0.53,49,2,57,100.92,152.68,3/16/23 20:24
co/TICKET-0067,2.26,3.53,25,48,75.03,198.11,270.88,3/17/23 5:53
co/TICKET-0068,5.24,0.85,-2,9,13.45,174.52,182.73,3/17/23 10:03
co/TICKET-0069,3.27,0.58,0,3,6,54.35,57.08,3/18/23 8:30
co/TICKET-0070,8.25,1.33,1,3,14,34.05,514.26,3/19/23 16:51
co/TICKET-0071,3.27,2.02,-2,8,11,227.61,235.33,3/19/23 17:03
co/TICKET-0072,5.22,0.65,-1,4,8,235.54,238.32,3/22/23 8:24
co/TICKET-0073,5.25,0.52,96,9,111.15,82.76,188.66,3/23/23 17:04
co/TICKET-0074,7.25,0.68,0,5,82,15.04,89.79,3/24/23 18:50
co/TICKET-0075,2.27,0.35,8,4,15,133.32,146.05,3/25/23 7:28
co/TICKET-0076,5.24,0.65,0,7,13,41.66,49.41,3/29/23 19:20
co/TICKET-0077,3.24,0.95,-1,34,37,107.77,141.53,3/30/23 6:18
co/TICKET-0078,6.27,0.85,-1,5,11.65,47.14,52.53,3/30/23 7:44
co/TICKET-0079,10.26,0.58,0,8,37.17,38.77,65.68,3/31/23 15:20
co/TICKET-0080,3.25,1.13,-2,3,5,182.74,184.5,4/1/23 1:19
co/TICKET-0081,2.26,0.42,-1,3,4,121.27,123.01,4/3/23 11:28
co/TICKET-0082,3.29,0.97,-1,3,6,111.73,114.44,4/4/23 1:13
co/TICKET-0083,5.23,0.7,31,2,39,43.28,77.05,4/4/23 5:12
co/TICKET-0084,4.29,0.88,0,130,151.43,4557.99,4705.13,4/7/23 7:13
co/TICKET-0085,2.25,0.47,4,8,15,51.25,64,4/10/23 21:11
co/TICKET-0086,7.24,0.32,0,4,14.77,94.28,101.81,4/12/23 19:16
co/TICKET-0087,7.24,0.23,-2,8,13.68,25.69,32.13,4/16/23 4:07
co/TICKET-0088,5.26,0.47,4,9,19.17,70.67,84.58,4/20/23 18:10
co/TICKET-0089,2.24,0.27,14,8,25,18.61,41.37,4/20/23 22:03
co/TICKET-0090,5.24,0.63,87,8,101,30.94,126.7,4/23/23 0:06
co/TICKET-0091,7.25,1.03,-3,8,13.13,96.34,102.22,4/23/23 0:38
co/TICKET-0092,2.29,0.4,15,5,23,47.03,67.74,4/24/23 10:04
co/TICKET-0093,5.28,0.2,6,7,19,13.37,27.09,4/24/23 17:13
co/TICKET-0094,6.3,0.58,-2,8,12.87,36.04,42.61,4/24/23 20:20
co/TICKET-0095,3.28,0.7,3,6,13,41.54,51.26,4/24/23 21:02
co/TICKET-0096,3.25,0.8,0,6,9,159.06,164.81,4/25/23 13:23
co/TICKET-0097,2.26,0.38,1,9,11,235.2,245.94,5/1/23 23:17
co/TICKET-0098,5.25,1.08,258,7,272.25,37.2,304.2,5/3/23 8:19
co/TICKET-0099,8.25,0.78,-1,3,11.17,54.25,57.17,5/3/23 9:56
co/TICKET-0100,11.27,0.22,-2,2,11.9,42.65,43.28,5/4/23 19:11
co/TICKET-0101,3.25,0.95,-2,44,47,227.03,270.78,5/8/23 13:43
co/TICKET-0102,3.24,2.2,12,9,27,100.09,123.85,5/9/23 17:08
co/TICKET-0103,3.28,2.07,1,8,13,36.55,46.27,5/11/23 7:26
co/TICKET-0104,6.25,0.5,95,54,156.48,0.67,150.9,5/12/23 21:50
co/TICKET-0105,6.25,0.6,108,56,171.23,33.39,198.38,5/18/23 2:21
co/TICKET-0106,4.29,0.53,0,18,23,66.02,84.73,5/18/23 16:32
co/TICKET-0107,5.28,0.55,45,9,60.15,13.98,68.85,5/18/23 20:32
co/TICKET-0108,5.28,0.58,34,25,65.18,39.03,98.93,5/18/23 21:12
co/TICKET-0109,5.23,0.73,14,4,24,191.51,210.28,5/20/23 15:52
co/TICKET-0110,3.3,0.33,-1,8,10,55.35,62.05,5/22/23 18:09
co/TICKET-0111,4.25,0.3,28,70,103.25,22.55,121.54,5/24/23 4:53
co/TICKET-0112,3.45,0.47,8,10,22.22,53.57,72.33,5/24/23 16:50
co/TICKET-0113,7.26,1.45,0,3,11,128.54,132.28,5/25/23 9:49
co/TICKET-0114,7.27,0.9,0,4,12,96,100.73,5/25/23 13:10
co/TICKET-0115,6.27,0.98,1,3,12.2,121.81,127.74,5/27/23 8:54
co/TICKET-0116,2.26,0.82,0,9,12.27,89.95,99.96,5/29/23 7:22
co/TICKET-0117,7.28,0.65,29,5,42,19.42,54.14,5/30/23 22:27
co/TICKET-0118,6.24,0.82,-2,7,12.85,120.09,126.7,6/1/23 1:26
co/TICKET-0119,5.31,0.63,44,55,105,37.02,136.71,6/2/23 9:00
co/TICKET-0120,5.25,0.98,14,8,29.18,74.25,98.18,6/3/23 0:38
co/TICKET-0121,7.25,0.42,84,8,100,99.4,192.15,6/5/23 3:22
co/TICKET-0122,6.26,0.33,13,9,29,39.84,62.58,6/5/23 14:13
co/TICKET-0123,5.27,0.35,2,9,17.22,53.5,65.45,6/6/23 3:16
co/TICKET-0124,5.24,0.83,24,17,48.9,115.13,158.78,6/6/23 12:11
co/TICKET-0125,5.27,0.33,54,24,84.18,24.29,103.2,6/6/23 12:32
co/TICKET-0126,2.29,0.27,2,9,12,152.69,162.4,6/10/23 4:46
co/TICKET-0127,4.27,0.63,1,6,12,44.14,51.87,6/14/23 21:29
co/TICKET-0128,4.31,0.42,0,77,81.77,195.99,273.44,6/16/23 21:28
co/TICKET-0129,5.31,0.68,35,3,45,56.54,96.23,6/19/23 19:27
co/TICKET-0130,3.25,0.47,11,34,49.43,246.07,292.24,6/20/23 3:52
co/TICKET-0131,3.28,0.25,1,2,7,63.57,67.29,6/21/23 17:37
co/TICKET-0132,5.27,0.42,4,6,16.35,16.76,27.84,6/22/23 23:21
co/TICKET-0133,3.27,0.57,22,12,38,67.21,101.94,6/23/23 22:08
co/TICKET-0134,3.28,0.52,0,7,11,89.47,97.18,6/25/23 13:59
co/TICKET-0135,6.27,1.53,-1,6,12.97,10.96,17.65,6/29/23 17:35
co/TICKET-0136,6.27,1.43,1,3,12.35,123.7,129.78,6/30/23 0:16
co/TICKET-0137,5.26,1.07,8,14,29.25,22.19,46.19,6/30/23 12:12
co/TICKET-0138,2.31,2.93,50,140,195.25,401.02,593.96,6/30/23 15:26
```

Google Docs link to .xlsx file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F919nbp8GucZaYfs45lVnN7hZtcuRciD/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110428622428089304236&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't return a hyperlink in a pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a Table but defined it for the entirety of columns A through I on sheet 'RawData'.

Instead, define it only on the used rows. When you paste rows at the bottom of the table, the table range will expand automatically.

I'm pretty sure there's no way you can get a hyperlink in a pivot table.

Let's try a different way using Power Query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="RAW"]}[Content],
    UseStartOfMonth = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Date/Time(in UTC)", Date.StartOfMonth, type datetime}}),
    RenameToStartOfMonth = Table.RenameColumns(UseStartOfMonth,{{"Date/Time(in UTC)", "StartOfMonth"}}),
    ConvertToDate = Table.TransformColumnTypes(RenameToStartOfMonth,{{"StartOfMonth", type date}}),
    UnpivotDuration = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(ConvertToDate, {"ID", "StartOfMonth"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    Groups = Table.Group(
        UnpivotDuration, 
        {"StartOfMonth", "Attribute"}, 
        {
            {"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type},
            {"P50", each List.Percentile([Value],0.5), type number}, 
            {"P90", each List.Percentile([Value],0.9), type number}, 
            {"Max", each List.Max([Value]), type number}
        }
    ),
    JoinCols = {"StartOfMonth","Attribute"},
    Joined = Table.Join(Groups,JoinCols & {"Max"},UnpivotDuration,JoinCols & {"Value"}),
    AddTicketLink = Table.AddColumn(Joined, "TicketLink", each "'=HYPERLINK(""https://some_url.com/" & [ID] & """," & Text.From([Max]) & ")"),
    RemoveValue = Table.RemoveColumns(AddTicketLink,{"Value","Max","ID"}),
    RenameTicketLinkToMax = Table.RenameColumns(RemoveValue,{{"TicketLink", "Max"}}),
    Sort = Table.Sort(RenameTicketLinkToMax,{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending},{"StartOfMonth",Order.Ascending}}),
    UnpivotMeasures = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Sort, {"StartOfMonth", "Attribute"}, "Attribute.1", "Value"),
    MergeDurationMeasure = Table.CombineColumns(UnpivotMeasures,{"Attribute", "Attribute.1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Measure Name"),
    PivotDurationMeasure = Table.Pivot(MergeDurationMeasure, List.Distinct(MergeDurationMeasure[#"Measure Name"]), "Measure Name", "Value", List.First)
in
    PivotDurationMeasure
```

That produces this:
[image]

The issue with using Power Query is that you can't insert formulas into a cell with a query refresh. Hence, following guidance from [here](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/09/12/powerquery-return-clickable-hyperlinks-to-excel/), I've put an apostrophe before each link.

Now you do a find/replace on the table (you can automate this if you choose):
[image]

This removes the apostrophe and in effect *activates* the hyperlink.

You can then format the columns using the 'Hyperlink' preset:
[image]

And apply any other formatting you want.

EDIT:

Revised AddTicketLink line to remove the "co/" from the ID field:

```
AddTicketLink = Table.AddColumn(Joined, "TicketLink", each "'=HYPERLINK(""https://some_url.com/" & Text.Middle([ID],3)) & """," & Text.From([Max]) & ")"),
```

Comment: You're only seeing the minimum usage.  This shared data as well as the linked spreadsheet uses dummy data and only a subset of the results in the pivot table. I assure you in the full sheet I'm using all of the columns A-I. I just know that if i can find the solution for Duration1, 2 and/or 3, I can replicate it for the others.  Additionally, im not at all familiar with Power Query and would prefer to use a native Excel solution, even if that means creating a separate table and reference data returned from the pivottable. This also means i dont have to install anything on my company laptop

Comment: I looked into power query and it seems the version of Excel already has it in it but renamed it.  I'll look further into your solution

Comment: Ok I got this to work, however... its not removing the "co/" so i either need an `$RIGHT (#REF,LEN(#REF)-3)` or (preferred) a `REPLACE(#REF,1,IF(ISERROR(FIND("co/",#REF)),0,3),"")` in here somewhere, but i'm getting hung up on the fact that #REF needs to be the text in column A that corresponds to the appropriate MAX value.

Comment: i tried adding a line in the power query:

Comment: @ScottMcCune - the query in my answer will unpivot an arbitrary number of duration columns. It unpivots all 7 that you already have in there, and will unpivot 50, 100 or however many columns there are in total. I get that the PQ code can look daunting, but it's really no less native Excel than a pivot table is. If you want to remove the "co/" from the hyperlink, change the 'AddTicketLink' line as shown in the edit to my answer. Text.Middle in PQ is equivalent to MID in Excel functions.

Comment: Oh, that works, but I played around with powerquery and found the Replace.Value fucntion and was able to come up with this: `= Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"co/","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"ID"})` as the second line in the query. 

This worked beautifully. Thank you, not only the solution but for pushing me towards Power Query.

Comment: Sorry for the thread necro here @FlexYourData, but I'm hoping you can help me refine this a bit further.  I've now been asked to see if its possible to retain everything we did in this solution, but also enable drill down into all the tickets, by month, but when the month collapsed, it will only show the values for p50, p90, & Max.   Google sheets doesnt support pivots but I created a visual example of what i mean (without the robust dynamic table that hyperlinks from power query) and took a screenshot here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e-OdfzrrSJUoC7vnUf6gubdnLtwCJbsK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh yeah, and am looking for the Grand Total row as well which would have the p50, p90 and MAX values for the full set (Ie: 3 months, 5 months, full year... however far along we are)